# Redshift: Case with Window Aggregate

Tags: case, amazon-redshift

To add a simple case condition as the last column, how would one edit the commented line #4 below to include a text label for each row indicative of whether the pricepaid was GT 3,275?

*Bonus points for if the perc_ttl_rev column is used instead based on mean for the entire derived column.

````
city, sum(qtysold) as qty_sold, sum(pricepaid)::int as revenue,    
round(ratio_to_report(sum(pricepaid)) over(), 2) as perc_ttl_rev 
-- case when sum(pricepaid) >3275 then 'above avg', else 'below avg' end) as foo                  
from sales, date, users
where sales.sellerid = users.userid
and sales.dateid = date.dateid
and year = 2008
and city = 'San Diego'                   
group by sellerid, username, name, city
order by revenue desc
limit 10;```

/*
sellerid username name city qty_sold revenue perc_ttl_rev

29069   SVL81MEQ    Axel Grant  San Diego   17  12667   0.15
49977   JJK84WTE    Julie Hanson    San Diego   22  7044    0.08
32759   SWY97TJG    Travis Powell   San Diego   4   5718    0.06999999999999999
18867   THC16BQG    Josephine Bailey    San Diego   13  5140    0.06
19750   AAS23BDR    Charity Zimmerman   San Diego   21  5007    0.06
43632   VAG08HKW    Griffin Dodson  San Diego   16  4868    0.06
46724   SXH43STL    Jena Burch  San Diego   13  3980    0.05
46357   WLH78HTP    Dalton Love San Diego   11  3276    0.04
36712   RXT40MKU    Hiram Turner    San Diego   14  2728    0.03
*/
````

Comment: Looking at this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CASE_function.html I would say something like `case when pricepaid = 3275 then 'was 3275' else 'not 3275' end`. As far as I know, a newly created column label `perc_ttl_rev` cannot be used in the same query

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to operate on the result of the aggregation (SUM()/GROUP BY) the CASE need to run after the aggregation.  The usual (and simplest) way to do this is nest your selects - aggregating in the inner select, performing CASE in the outer.

If for some reason you need to keep things in a single select layer then there are only 3 things that run after aggregation - order by, having, and window functions.  Order by and having won't do what you want but you might be able to hack together something in a window function (MIN()?) that does what you are looking for.  The best answer is nested selects.

Comment: Thank you very much, Bill. I was thinking of simply generating a TEMP table from the query listed above, then CASE on the perc_ttl_rev column to keep debugging clean as I'm cycling over from mysql syntax, so sub queries are still a learning area for me.